# Finding the maximum of NDSolve's result

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I'm solving a set of differential equations as follows:

```
s = NDSolve[{p'[t] == -gamma p[t] f[t], f'[t] == -c f[t] + gamma p[t] f[t], 
 T'[t] == b (1 - T[t]) (r^n/(f[t]^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T[t]) - m (f[t]^n/(f[t]^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T[t]), p[0] == p0, 
 f[0] == 0.001, T[0] == T0} /. {gamma -> 0.5431799751931238`, b -> 0.08850801132176628`, m -> 0.9780307913586779`, 
 r -> 0.8264557187463307`, n -> 14.983207992804674`, c -> 0.006, p0 -> 0.8`, T0 -> 0.8`}, {p, f, T}, {t, 0, 72}];

p2 = Plot[Evaluate[{T[t], f[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 72}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {T, f}]
```

[image]

The blue curve corresponds to the variable $f$ in the equations. How can I find the coordinates of the maximum of this curve? (And the same for the red curve, its maximum and also its minimum.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
FindRoot[(D[T[t], t] /. s) == 0, {t, 20}]

(*  {t -> 17.9042}  *)
```

or this:

```
FindMaximum[T[t] /. s, {t, 20}]

(*  {0.956916, {t -> 17.9042}}  *)
```

and the same with the second function.

Have fun!

Comment: @Anovice: `FindInstance[{((f /. s)[[1]][t] - 0.025) == 0, 
  t >= 0 && t <= 72}, t, Reals,2]` results in `{{t -> 7.57455}, {t -> 7.57455}}` and `NMinimize[{((f /. s)[[1]][t] - 0.025)^2, t >= 0 && t <= 72}, t]` performs `{1.14078*10^-19, {t -> 7.57455}}`.

Comment: @A novice it works for the function f: `FindRoot[((f[t] /. s) - 0.0025) == 0, {t, 1}]` yielding `{t -> 2.13987}`.  In the case of T(t), there is something weird with the solution. You can see it by warnings. There is a workaround: `FindMinimum[((T[t] /. s) - 0.0025)^2, {t, 30}]` returning: `{1.4399*10^-8, {t -> 31.3609}}`.

Comment: From where do you know `20` in `FindRoot[(D[T[t], t] /. s) == 0, {t, 20}]?
`

Comment: @user64494 From the plot.

Comment: @AlexeiBoubitch: Thank you. `NMaximize` does need any plot.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done as follows.

```
NMaximize[{(f /. s)[[1]][t], t >= 0 && t <= 72}, t]
```

> `{0.742649, {t -> 25.7451}}`

```
NMaximize[{(T /. s)[[1]][t], t >= 0 && t <= 72}, t]
```

> `{0.956916, {t -> 17.9042}}`

```
NMinimize[{(T /. s)[[1]][t], t >= 0 && t <= 72}, t]
```

> `{0.00261999, {t -> 33.1547}}`

Answer (score 2):

Here are three approaches with increasing accuracy that take advantage of the data computed by `NDSolve`:

**(1)**
The maximum value of `T[t]` and the value of `t` at the maximum, among the steps computed by `NDSolve`:

```
maxPos = PositionLargest[T["ValuesOnGrid"] /. First[s]];
maxTVal = Extract[T["ValuesOnGrid"] /. First[s], maxPos]
maxt1Val =
 First@Extract[T["Grid"] /. First[s], maxPos]
(*
0.9569154933291244`     
17.89633907171858` 
*)
```

**(2)**
The maximum of the interpolating function returned by `NDSolve`, which occurs between the steps computed by `NDSolve` but contains but contains additional error from the approximation by the interpolation:

```
maxTPVal = Extract[T'["ValuesOnGrid"] /. First[s], maxPos]
maxt2Val =
 First@Extract[T["Grid"] /. First[s], maxPos + Sign[maxTPVal]]
FindMaximum[T[t] /. First[s], {t, maxt1Val, maxt2Val}]
(*  {0.9569156862237768`, {t -> 17.904199030539463`}}  *)
```

One can reduce the error due to interpolation by add the option `InterpolationOrder -> All` to `NDSolve`. It affects the 6th digit of precision slightly, so the extra precision may not be needed in some cases.

Replace `T` by `f` to get the corresponding results for `f[t]`.

**(3)**
The following computes the maximum using `NDSolve` (you have to plan ahead and include the code that saves the maximum values). `WhenEvent` will locate the maximum as accurately as the ODE integration method allows.

```
maxT = {0., 0.};
{ode, ics} = {
    {p'[t] == -gamma  p[t]  f[t]
     , f'[t] == -c  f[t] + gamma  p[t]  f[t]
     , T'[t] == 
      b  (1 - T[t])  (r^n/(f[t]^n + r^n))  (1 - 0.00262/T[t]) - 
       m  (f[t]^n/(f[t]^n + r^n))  (1 - 0.00262/T[t])}
    , {p[0] == p0, f[0] == 0.001, T[0] == T0}
    } /. {gamma -> 0.5431799751931238`, b -> 0.08850801132176628`, 
    m -> 0.9780307913586779`, r -> 0.8264557187463307`, 
    n -> 14.983207992804674`, c -> 0.006, p0 -> 0.8`, T0 -> 0.8`};
derivSol = First@Solve[ode, {T'[t], f'[t], p'[t]}];
s = NDSolve[{ode, ics,
    WhenEvent[T'[t] < 0, If[T[t] > maxT[[2]], maxT = {t, T[t]}]; 
      "RestartIntegration"] /. derivSol,
    WhenEvent[f'[t] < 0, maxf = {t, f[t]}; "RestartIntegration"] /. 
     derivSol}
   , {p, f, T}, {t, 0, 72}];

maxT
maxf
(*
{17.904137483723822`, 0.9569156846482132`} 
{25.74518018578614`, 0.7426487539346786`} 
*)
```

You could use a similar `If[]` statement to save the maximum of `f[t]`, if `f[t]` might not have just one maximum. (`T[t]` has several maximum due to jitter when we have `T[t] == 0` approximately, between around `t == 30` and `t == 40`.)

*Remark:* In fact, the length of the interval where `T[t]` is approximately zero can vary depending on `PrecisionGoal`, `AccuracyGoal`, `WorkingPrecision` and `WhenEvent[]`. It makes me wonder if the jump up from `T[t] == 0` in the OP's plot is an anomaly due to rounding error.